# Receiving a error saying that stack is empty in java leetcode

Tags: java, oop, collections, queue, stack

The code for the same is here

class MyQueue {

```
Stack<Integer> mainS;
Stack<Integer> helperS;
 // Stack<Integer> mainS =new Stack<>();
 // Stack<Integer> helperS =new Stack<>();

public MyQueue() {
      mainS =new Stack<>();
      helperS =new Stack<>();
}

public void push(int x) {
    if(mainS.size()>0){
         mainS.push(x);
    }
   
}

public int pop() {
    while(mainS.size() >1){
        helperS.push((mainS.pop()));
    }
    int val = mainS.pop();

    mainS.add(helperS.pop());

    return val;
}

public int peek() {
    while(mainS.size() >1){
        helperS.push((mainS.pop()));
    }
    int val1 = mainS.pop();
    helperS.push(val1);

    mainS.add(helperS.pop());

    return val1;
}

public boolean empty() {
    if(mainS.size()==0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

}

/**

- Your MyQueue object will be instantiated and called as such:
- MyQueue obj = new MyQueue();
- obj.push(x);
- int param_2 = obj.pop();
- int param_3 = obj.peek();
- boolean param_4 = obj.empty();
  */

The error coming is that
*java.util.EmptyStackException

at line 102, java.base/java.util.Stack.peek

at line 84, java.base/java.util.Stack.pop

at line 35, MyQueue.peek

at line 69, **Driver**.**helperSelectMethod**

at line 89, **Driver**.**helper**

at line 110, **Driver**.main*

The Logic is correct
Please help someone.

Comment: You haven't asked a question, nor provided any details about the error.

Comment: In your push method you check if the size is already greater than 0 and only then actually push something into the stack. I don't know how you expect an empty stack to ever fill with that logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below code

```
 public void push(int x) {
    if(mainS.size()>0){
         mainS.push(x);
    }
  }
```

with

```
    public void push(int x) {
         mainS.push(x);
   }
```

You are checking the size of the stack should be greater than 0 before you are pushing. But it will be 0 when you create it and you will never push if it's 0 so it will always be empty.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes it was a problem and also in the peek() and push() when i am pushing elements from helper stack to main stack then i should do it in while loop . Silly mistake. _**Thanks for the help.**_